# How to fix the error for creating table given below

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' (   
'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
'username' varchar(255) NOT NULL,   
'first_name' varchar(255) NOT NULL,   
'last_name' varchar(255) NOT NULL,   
'email' varchar(255) NOT NULL,   
'password' varchar(32) NOT NULL,   
'sign_up_date' date NOT NULL,   
'activated' enum('0','1') NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY ('id')  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''users' (   'id' int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   'username' varchar(255) NO' at line 1

Comment: get rid off single quotes on table and column names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these SQL useful to you. Just replace ' with `.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `sign_up_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `activated` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id))
    ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.5148 seconds.)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, `sign_up_date` DATE NOT NULL, `activated` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Comment: what does it mean by empty result set?

Comment: Sorry, I just like a warning message don't worry about that message. if you refresh the database and see table is available or not. You satisfied my answer and give a tick mark and up vote please.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `announcement` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`schoolid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: Please use proper formatting on your answer, and provide some commentary on how it improves the accepted 5 year old answer.